# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyee.asyncio'" on playwright

Tags: python, python-3.x, playwright

This is my environment:

```
ubuntu18.04(wsl2)
playwright 1.29.1
pyee 8.22
scrapy-playwright 0.024
```

Here is my code:

```
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright
import time

async def main():
    async with async_playwright() as p:
        browser = await p.chromium.launch_persistent_context(headless=False, user_data_dir='', args=['--disable-infobars'])
        page = await browser.new_page()
        await page.goto('https://www.baidu.com')
        time.sleep(100)
        await page.close()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Here is my traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/edmounds/tieba/test2.py", line 2, in <module>
    from playwright.async_api import async_playwright
  File "/home/edmounds/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/playwright/async_api/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    import playwright.async_api._generated
  File "/home/edmounds/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/playwright/async_api/_generated.py", line 25, in <module>
    from playwright._impl._accessibility import Accessibility as AccessibilityImpl
  File "/home/edmounds/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_accessibility.py", line 17, in <module>
    from playwright._impl._connection import Channel
  File "/home/edmounds/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_connection.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pyee.asyncio import AsyncIOEventEmitter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyee.asyncio'
```

I have checked the pyee package.
I also tried `import pyee`, but it didn't work.

Comment: It seems your environment is missing the pyee package. How did you install playwright? Because pyee is one of the dependencies of playwright, and should have been also installed when installing playwright.

Comment: What is the output of `pip list` and does it show playwright and pyee?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. I installed `playwright 1.30.0` then `playwright install`, then copy-pasted your code as-is, then it ran without errors. I am on a macOS, in case the OS matters.

Comment: yes, it show playwright and pyee,and i have just reinstalled playwright

Comment: I resinstall a newer pyee and it works

Comment: @Edmounds Please write an answer to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I also executed the command for playwright install. the module pyee was installed and the issue was resolved.

```
pip install playwright
```

**Output:**

```
Requirement already satisfied: playwright in lib/python3.11/site-packages (1.29.1)
Requirement already satisfied: greenlet==2.0.1 in lib/python3.11/site-packages (from playwright) (2.0.1)
Collecting pyee==9.0.4
  Using cached pyee-9.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in lib/python3.11/site-packages (from pyee==9.0.4->playwright) (4.4.0)
Installing collected packages: pyee
  Attempting uninstall: pyee
    Found existing installation: pyee 8.1.0
    Uninstalling pyee-8.1.0:
      Successfully uninstalled pyee-8.1.0
Successfully installed pyee-9.0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do

```
pip install playwright
```

Then run the command

```
playwright install
```

This may take a while but that's what I did and it worked.

Comment: I have already do these things,but it still give me this erro

Comment: That’s weird, make sure you’re running this in a Python environment, you could try restarting your editor or even the computer, or even uninstall and reinstall playwright. Maybe another thing is install the missing modules directly?

Comment: @Edmounds You can try `pip install --force-reinstall playwright`. Maybe something went wrong and pyee didn't get installed when you installed playwright. Make sure you also don't have a `--no-deps` option set.

Comment: That should work^

Comment: No,it didn't work as expected@Shane Gevais

Answer (score 0):

use:

pyee==9.0.4
playwright

since:

ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
playwright 1.34.0 requires pyee==9.0.4, but you have pyee 9.1.0 which is incompatible.

also remove pyppeteer